# Rx Observables: emit additional item for each original item, reduce them to another type, consume

Tags: java, couchbase, rx-java, observable, couchbase-java-api

I am having problems doing the following using Couchbase Java client 2.2.2 and Rx Observables 1.0.15:

- I have a list of strings which are document names
- Along with each original document for a document name I would like to load another document (deduced from the original document name) so I would get a pair of documents. If any of those two documents do not exist, do not use this pair any more.
- If the pair is valid (i.e. both documents exist) then use both documents to create a custom object from them
- combine those transformed items into a list

What I have come up with so far looks really mean:

```
List<E> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

Observable
    .from(originalDocumentNames)
    .flatmap(key -> {
        Observable firstDocument = bucket.async().get(key);
        Observable secondDocument = bucket.async().get(getSecondKeyNameFrom(key));
        return Observable.merge(firstDocument, secondDocument);
    })
    .reduce((jsonDocument1, jsonDocument2) -> {
        if (jsonDocument1 == null || jsonDocument2 == null) {
            return null;
        }
        resultList.add(createCustomObject(jsonDocument1, jsonDocument2);
        return null;
    })
    .filter(Objects.nonNull)
    .singleOrDefault(null)
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<E>() {
        public void onComplete() {
            //use resultList in a callback function
        }
    });
```

This does not work. I do not know where, but I think I am using `Observable.merge` the wrong way.
Also I think I am approaching the whole problem the wrong way.

So the main questions it seems are:

- how do I emit an additional item to an Observable stream?
- how can I reduce two items into an item of another type? (reduce(T, T, T) does not allow that)
- am I taking it on wrong?

Comment: I've not much experience with RxJava — work in the Scala world mostly, but the normal way to expand elements is exactly what you are doing: you either `flatMap`, expanding or shrinking the elements as you wish, or use `flatMapIterable` if you can provide the expansion immediately.

Comment: What you may want to do (and what SO guidelines tell you, anyway) is to reduce the example, removing all the details (what's `bucket`? Why would anyone care?) until you have a minimal self-containing example reproducing the problem. It well may help you solve the problem as you go.

Comment: You might want to play with the zip() function instead of merge() and reduce(). http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Comment: @alf It is already most minimal. And "bucket" in the context if a Couchbase application is pretty clear.

Comment: @JohnScattergood When using zip() the processed elements overlap. I want to emit two items, process these two into a new one and not use any of the original items in the next processing step.

Comment: Should it be ordered ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `zip` *inside* the flatmap. Zip will emit as many items as the `Observable` with the fewest items. So if one of the documents is missing, its sequence will be empty and zip will skip it.

```
Observable
.from(originalDocumentNames)
.flatmap(key -> {
    //the stream of 0-1 original document
    Observable firstDocument = bucket.async().get(key);
    //the stream of 0-1 associated document
    Observable secondDocument = bucket.async().get(getSecondKeyNameFrom(key));

    //using zip and the createCustomObject method reference as a zip function to combine pairs of documents
    return Observable.zip(firstDocument, secondDocument, this::createCustomObject);
})
.toList() //let RxJava aggregate into a List
.subscribe(
    //the "callback" function, onNext will be called only once with toList
    list -> doSomething(list), 
    //always try to define onError (best practice)
    e -> processErrors(e)
);
```

Comment: Thx, that does it. Didn't think of a zip inside a flatmap.

Answer (score 1):

There's several issue in this code :

1. side effect, the `reduce` operation is adding to a list outside the `Observable` chain, that's wrong. The `reduce` should either return the list or don't exists at all as Rx has a `toList` operation. Also because of the reduce operation that returns `null` the next operations have to handle that ; this is rather inelegant.
2. `merge` operation is wrong, you should instead `zip` in the `flatmap` and build the pair/aggregate.
3. Optional point : the *flatmap* operation does not handle if either get operation will return multiple items (maybe that's *de facto* the case with couchbase)

Note I don't have an IDE so no code for now. But in my point replacing `merge` by `zip` and removing `reduce` certainly should help.